# Angularjs removing # in the url when app is in subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I currently have my angularjs app loading for the /reports section of my site only.  To clarify, the site is a PHP CMS but /reports is an angular app.  I tried the following code to remove the # but now when I visit /reports it redirects the site to / and loads the angular app

```
'use strict';

angular.module('logs', [
    'ngRoute',
    'logs.services',
    'logs.controllers'
  ]).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/configs', {templateUrl: '/js/reports/configs.html', controller: 'configs'});
    $routeProvider.when('/sitelog', {templateUrl: '/js/reports/table.html', controller: 'table'});

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

Then on the /reports index page where I init the app I added

```
<base href="/reports">
```

I'm just trying to get /reports/configs and /reports/sitelog to work without #'s.

Comment: is server set up to manage the virtual directories and load app entry point?

Comment: you can't selectively use html5Mode for only some portions of your app.

Comment: You have do not have a $routeProvider.when('/reports', {templateUrl: '/js/reports/index.html', controller: 'table'}); defined. Hence, you are being redirected to the default route. However, your server also needs to be setup so that  it does not serve up the default index page. Rather it needs to let angular do the call.

Comment: /reports isn't a route in the app it's the landing page in the php cms where the angular app is loaded

Comment: I am using html5mode for the entire angular app which is loaded on a sub directory in a php cms